# How to get parent of a node with some specific value in xml using lxml python

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I am new to xml, and have problem in parsing it.
I have following xml:

```
<bookstore>
  <book>
    <name>abc</name>
    <price>30</price>
  </book>
  <book>
     <name>Learning XML</name>
     <price>56</price>
  </book>
  <book>
     <name>Learning Java</name>
     <price>340</price>
  </book>
  <book>
     <name>Learning Python</name>
     <price>560</price>
  </book>
</bookstore>
```

I want to get the name of book whose price is 30. How to do that using lml python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following XPath to select `<name>` element of `<book>` whose `<price>` equals 30 :

```
//book[price=30]/name
```

Python example :

```
from lxml import etree
tree = etree.parse('path_to_your_xml.xml')
result = tree.xpath('//book[price=30]/name')[0]
print result.text
#above printed abc
```